# OracleConnectionPoolManager throws an exception in its finalizer

Tags: c#, oracle, mono

I'm writing a command line tool in Mono that (among other things) connects to our Oracle database. It appears to work fine, but I get this exception at the end:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
  at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionPoolManager.Dispose () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionPoolManager.Finalize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

What's going on ? I am tempted to just catch that exception and ignore it... Except I can't do that, because it is thrown from the finalizer, which runs after main() returns.

Answer (score 0):

It seems when setting the connection pool to false this is a workaround for the problem - see https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=27546